# Masking DatetimeIndex DataFrame with time indexed frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Suppose I have the the following DataFrame of data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
import datetime as dt  

index = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp("2020/01/01 06:00:00"), pd.Timestamp("2020/10/20 20:00:00"), freq='8H')

n = len(index)

data_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.random(n), 'B': np.random.random(n), 'C': np.random.random(n)}, index=index)
```

Then suppose I have the following mask DataFrame:

```
mask_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan,1,1], 'B': [1,np.nan,np.nan], 'C': [1, np.nan, 1]}, index=[dt.time(6),dt.time(14),dt.time(20)])
```

I wish to mask `data_df` with `mask_df` such that at every time where there is a `np.nan` in `mask_df` this will become a `np.nan` in `data_df`

What is the most succinct pandas methodology to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

Inserting a new column just with the time:

```
data_df['time'] = data_df.index.time
```

Then filling the nan values according to the mask:

```
for col in mask_df:
    nan_rows = [*mask_df.loc[mask_df[col].isna()].index]
    data_df.loc[data_df['time'].isin(nan_rows), col] = np.nan

data_df.head()

                    A           B           C           time
2020-01-01 06:00:00 NaN         0.022417    0.179227    06:00:00
2020-01-01 14:00:00 0.935356    NaN         NaN         14:00:00
2020-01-01 22:00:00 0.578508    0.170026    0.740205    22:00:00
2020-01-02 06:00:00 NaN         0.903510    0.801487    06:00:00
2020-01-02 14:00:00 0.720165    NaN         NaN         14:00:00
```

If you want to drop the 'time' column:

```
data_df.drop(columns = 'time', inplace = True)
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve loops